# How to increment variable in the middle of URL and output for multiple queries?

Tags: python, json

I would like to modify the code below to allow for searching multiple stores at once (via the four digit store number in the 'data' section below). What is the best way to accomplish this? Preferably I would be able to limit the search to 50-100 stores.

```
import requests
import json

js = requests.post("http://www.walmart.com/store/ajax/search",
                data={"searchQuery":"store=2516&size=18&dept=4044&query=43888060"} ).json()

data = json.loads(js['searchResults'])

res = data["results"][0]
print(res["name"], res["inventory"])
```

I would also like the store # printed in the line above.

Answer (score 0):

Your `data` object in the request.post call can be constructed like any other string. And then a variable that represents it can take the place of your "store=2516..." string. Like this, assuming `requests` is defined in the outer function someplace and can be reused:

```
var stores = ["2516","3498","5478"];
stores.forEach( makeTheCall );

function makeTheCall( element, index, array ) {
  storeQuery = "store=" + element + "&size=18&dept=4044&query=43888060";
  js = requests.post("http://www.walmart.com/store/ajax/search",
            data={"searchQuery":storeQuery} ).json()
  data = json.loads(js['searchResults'])
  res = data["results"][0]
  console.log("name: " + res["name"] + ", store: " + element + ", inventory: " + res["inventory"]);
}
```

I'm not familiar with your use of "print", but I've only ever used client side javascript.

Comment: Err.  Question was about Python, not Javascript.

Comment: Haha, I have been staring at javascript all day and didn't notice. Sorry. I wouldn't be suprised if the gyst of my answer doesn't work anyway. Just iterate over your array of store numbers, and for each one construct a string and submit it to your request.post function as the value of the searchQuery property. Instead of stores.forEach you would want to use `for store in stores`

Answer (score 0):

The API does not support searching for multiple stores, so you need to make multiple requests.

```
import requests
import json
from collections import defaultdict

results = defaultdict(list)

stores = [2516, 1234, 5678]
url = "http://www.walmart.com/store/ajax/search"
query = "store={}&size=18&dept=4044&query=43888060"

for store in stores:
   r = requests.post(url, data={'searchQuery': query.format(store)})
   r.raise_for_status()
   try:
       data = json.loads(r.json()['searchResults'])['results'][0]
       results[store].append((data['name'],data['inventory']))
   except IndexError:
       continue

for store, data in results.iteritems():
   print('Store: {}'.format(store))
   if data:
       for name, inventory in data:
          print('\t{} - {}'.format(name, inventory))
```

Comment: Thanks - this works, although it will error out if a given store does not have inventory based on the json returned for the specific store. Suggestions on working around that?

Comment: Just add a try/except to it.

Comment: In looking at the json for the stores it looks like those with no inventory will have a json with "'results': []" vs "'results': [lots of variables]'. How could I structure the query to bypass those with blank results? - Just saw your reply - I'll look into the try/expect recommendation. Thanks!!